# Custom layout for my toolbar with buttons . Should I create a JavaClass for it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have an android-studio app with custom toolbar. I use a layout for my toolbar with buttons and I call it with <'include> in every activity. I used android:onClick in the xml for the buttons.

The problem is, that I am not sure how I should connect my buttons (located in my toolbar layout) since I have no Java Class for it. If I create a Java Class I should extend it and I normally use Activity/AppCompatActivity, but my toolbar layout is not activity and the app crashes when I click the buttons in the emulator.

So how should I make the buttons work?

Comment: You have to define onClick method in every activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways to do it. I can show quickly 2 ways in pseudo code :

Solution 1 :

Layout activity :

```
<Coordinator>

     <AppBarLayout>
         <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>
     </AppBarLayout>
</Coordinator>
```

Layout Toolbar :

```
<Toolbar id="@+id/toolbar">
     <TextView id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"/>
</Toolbar>
```

Activity :

```
onCreate() {
toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_toolbar_title);

setToolbar(toolbar);
//handle click on view if you want
}
```

Solution 2 :

Layout activity

```
<Coordinator>
         <AppBarLayout>
             <CustomToolbar  id="@+id/customToolbar""/>
         </AppBarLayout>
</Coordinator>
```

Custom Toolbar Class => CustomView

```
CustomToolbar extends Toolbar {
   //find your views


}
```

Layout custom toolbar :

```
<merge>
         <TextView id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"/>
//other views needed
</merge>
```

In your activity you will have the customtoolbar :

```
onCreate() {
    toolbar = (CustomToolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

}
```